# Strange behavior on mobile device running app script / wrong data shown in cells after hide/unhide columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote some app script running in a google spreadsheet that gives me a weather forecast for a column of GPS coordinates. For UI purposes I hide and unhide columns for the mobile device user. Everything works great and the values in the various cells are all correct. But it is not SHOWN correct on Android phones. It appears to the user that values from other cells are located in the wrong cells - strange. It's just a visual problem.

If I manually change from dark theme to light theme on the mobile device (or vice versa) then everything looks the way it should.

If I stop hiding/unhiding columns the problem goes away, but would really like this to work as is -- again, just a visual display problem with the sheets app. How can I refresh the screen?

Ideas?

The cells should be showing the value that is actually in them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I need to move on -- just thought I'd see if anyone else had experience with this. Simplifying the code enough to share with the community is too involved in this case. It all works fine in my desktop browser. And on mobiles, the fact that the cell values are all correct and display correctly after changing the mobile device from dark theme to light theme (or vice versa) indicates that there is some display glitch.

So, the best "solution" at this time is to avoid the situation. I stopped hiding/unhiding columns and I am OK with it.